# BIOS Stuck after PCIe Enumeration

Tags: x86, x86-64, enumeration, bios, pci-e

We are developing a custom PCIe card on FPGA. After programming the FPGA, we can read the PCIe configuration and it seems correct.

When we connect this PCIe card on a Jetson TX2, it works fine.

But, when we connect this on an x86_64 PC, (ASUS PRIME x299 Delux MB), the bios hangs.
Q-CODES on the MB shows 92, d5 and later 97(Stuck)

```
92 - PCI Bus initialization is started.
D5 - No Space for Legacy Option ROM.
97 - Console Output devices connect.
```

Why does it works on Jetson and not on x86?

What can be done to solve the issue?

Is there any way to get debug logs from BIOS?

Comment: What about the `D5` error? Have you tried disabling the Option ROM in the card?

Comment: We don't have option ROM on our card. In normal boot, without our card, D5 is being shown after 92. So I think it's some other device's.

Comment: Probably true. Are the standard PCI config regs correct? I don't think there a better method than removing everything from the card until you have the BIOS boot, then reassemble it back piece by piece until you find the faulting one. From here it's impossible to answer, it could be anything (including the violation of the PCIe electrical characteristics, the Jetson TX2 being simply more tolerant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got it working. It seems that the expansion ROM was enabled. It works fine after disabling it. Thanks @Margaret Bloom.